# How mail transfer works between the Senders SMTP and the receivers SMTP

Tags: email, smtp, email-server, tcp

when I send an E-Mail it works like this:

My E-Mail Client -> My SMTP -> Recipients SMTP -> Recipients E-Mail Client

I know the way how my E-Mail client communicates with my SMTP but how do the SMTP Servers communicate with each orher? How the data is being transmitted? Could someone paste something like a Telnet log?

Comment: Do a google for "send email via telnet" and you'll find the conversation style communications that happen

Comment: @ivanivan I mean the communication between the 2 SMTP servers

Comment: It is same communication ....

Comment: Please see [Wikipedia: SMTP transport example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#SMTP_transport_example) or just have a look at the [standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To actually answer your question.

Just like your email client initiates an SMTP conversation like so (if you were to do it via telnet)

```
    MAIL FROM: <from@fromdomain.com>
    RCPT TO: <to@todomain.com>
    DATA
    Blah blah blah text
    .(period)
```

- You email server will then typically queue the email.
- When it's ready to send it, it will do an DNS lookup for the domain, find the MX record (or A record if no MX exists).  This is how it knows which server to start talking with
- Finally, it will initiate the same exact conversation you just had to your mail server (the one in the quote block), to the recipients mail server.  From there, it depends on the recipients mail server.

***Note, the smtp commands I outline are non-encyrpted / non-auth and overly simplified.